# Give an example of ring that has two maximal chains of prime ideals of different lengths.

Tags: abstract-algebra, commutative-algebra, krull-dimension

Give an example of ring that has two maximal chains of prime  ideals of different lengths.

Is there an easy example?

Comment: It might be useful to know that a ring in which all maximal chain of primes have the same length are affine domains.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

$\mathbb Z\times F$ where $F$ is a field.

One maximal chain is $\mathbb Z\times\{0\}$ (of length $0$)

and another is $\{0\}\times F\subseteq (p)\times F$ for a prime $p$.